# remove all duplicate class elements, except for the first one

Tags: jquery, duplicates

I have a dynamic page that loads 2, 3,4,etc..links onto a page that looks like this...

```
<a class="mgoogle" href="http://google.com">to go google</a>
```

If that link loads on a page and displays five times like this...

```
<a class="mgoogle" href="http://google.com">to go google</a>
<a class="mgoogle" href="http://google.com">to go google</a>
<a class="mgoogle" href="http://google.com">to go google</a>
<a class="mgoogle" href="http://google.com">to go google</a>
<a class="mgoogle" href="http://google.com">to go google</a>
```

How can I remove all of them except the first one with jquery?  FYI - it may generate any quantity and may not be 5.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should works:

```
$(".mgoogle:not(:first)").remove();
```

Comment: @blackhawk - is there no need to check if the HREF and link content is identical?

Comment: they will always be identitcal, they will never change